# Trying to implement PrimeNG in Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng-datatable

I am just trying to implement PrimeNG library in my Angular 4 project. I can see PrimeNG in my dependecies and also in my nodemodules folder but when I just did a simple:

```
        <p-dataTable >
           <p-column ></p-column>
           <p-column ></p-column>
           <p-column ></p-column>
           <p-column ></p-column>
       </p-dataTable>
```

Here's the error in my console's browser:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'p-column' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-column' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-column' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

        <p-dataTable >
       [ERROR ->]<p-column ></p-column>
       <p-column ></p-column>
       <p-column ></p-column>
       "): ng:///AppModule/TableaudebordComponent.html@5:4
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { TableaudebordComponent } from './tableaudebord.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { ToggleComponent }  from './toggle.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routeConfig } from './router-config';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service'; //  <-- #1 import  service

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule,     RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig)
 ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent, DashboardComponent,          PageNotFoundComponent, NavbarComponent,PetitPaveInfraComponent,   PaveInfraComponent, PetitPaveAppliComponent, DashboardnextComponent, Dashboardnext2Component, Dashboardnext3Component,  PetitPaveProblemComponent, PaveProblemComponent, ToggleComponent,   TableaudebordComponent ],
providers: [ UserService ], 
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you post your `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: @Hackerman I update my post with app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the modules needed for whatever PrimeNG compenent you want to use. In this instance you want to add `DataTableModule` & `SharedModule` to the `imports` array in your `app.module.ts` after importing the modules like from primeng:

`import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';`

`imports: [..., DataTableModule, SharedModule]`

Comment: Yes I did it I import DataTableModule as following import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

Comment: Where, in your `UserService`?

Comment: If you take the `HttpModule` in your `app.module.ts` as an example you see near the top you import the actual module: `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` then you add the imported module to your applications module imports so that you can use it in your application: `@NgModule({
 imports:      [ BrowserModule, **HttpModule**,     RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig)
 ],` you need to do the same thing here. As @Hackerman is suggesting you have not imported these in your `app.module.ts`